# Parse a Javascript Object into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, so I have a Javascript object that I printout to the console into the following form:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {data: 50, label: "Active Users"}
1: {data: 20, label: "Expired Users"}
2: {data: 30, label: "Renewed Users"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am trying to extract out the `data` and `label` values into separate arrays.

This is what I have done:

```
    var dataObject = doughnutdata;
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataObject));
    console.log(obj);
    var labelsdata = [];
    var datadummy = [];
    labelsdata.push(obj.label);
    datadummy.push(obj.data);
    console.log(labelsdata);
    console.log(datadummy);
```

But I get `[undefined]` for both `labelsdata` and `datadummy`.

On a sidenote, this is how I have set my `doughnutdata`:

```
var doughnutdata = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.dummysubscribeddata));
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use the JSON methods here. No reason at all.

Comment: `obj` is still an array and arrays don't have `label` or `data` properties.

Comment: You'd need to iterate the array to push the values. `obj` is an array and doesn't have keys assigned. So: `obj.forEach((item) => { labelsdata.push(item.label) });` etc.

Comment: @Pointy I got confused by: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.dummysubscribeddata));` because this converts an object into `JSON`

Comment: @RahulSharma right, and then `@HTML.Raw()` drops it directly into JavaScript where it will be interpreted as a JavaScript object.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 1):

Try simple loop.

```js
let values = [
  {data: 50, label: "Active Users"},
  {data: 50, label: "Active Users"},
  {data: 50, label: "Active Users"},
  {data: 50, label: "Active Users"},
];

let data = [];
let label = [];

for(const value of values) {
  data.push(value.data);
  label.push(value.label);
}

console.log('data: ', data);
console.log('label: ', label);
```

Comment: This also works. Thanks